# Unable to instantiate application on path: DexPathList

Tags: kotlin, gradle, classnotfoundexception

I saw this problem and I don't know what caused it or how to solve it
Simply the application crashed with no reason and nothing weird!

this is the problem from logcat:

```
2021-12-01 00:08:56.105 27747-27747/com.example.halanchallenge E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.halanchallenge, PID: 27747
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.halanchallenge.presentation.utils.manager.BaseApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.halanchallenge.presentation.utils.manager.BaseApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~AByZTfuIHlZhPYmwpjE5lQ==/com.example.halanchallenge-B7fNXgixWuCCl0Iug8pygQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~AByZTfuIHlZhPYmwpjE5lQ==/com.example.halanchallenge-B7fNXgixWuCCl0Iug8pygQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1332)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7469)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7440)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:301)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.halanchallenge.presentation.utils.manager.BaseApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~AByZTfuIHlZhPYmwpjE5lQ==/com.example.halanchallenge-B7fNXgixWuCCl0Iug8pygQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~AByZTfuIHlZhPYmwpjE5lQ==/com.example.halanchallenge-B7fNXgixWuCCl0Iug8pygQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1158)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1324)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7469) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7440) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:301) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/halanchallenge/presentation/utils/manager/Hilt_BaseApplication;
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
            ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.halanchallenge.presentation.utils.manager.Hilt_BaseApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~AByZTfuIHlZhPYmwpjE5lQ==/com.example.halanchallenge-B7fNXgixWuCCl0Iug8pygQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~AByZTfuIHlZhPYmwpjE5lQ==/com.example.halanchallenge-B7fNXgixWuCCl0Iug8pygQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 18 more
```

And this is my gradle file :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.halanchallenge"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", BASE_URL)
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
  
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'

    //GIF
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.7.0"

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.2"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.1'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"

    //GSON
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'

    // Navigation Components
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"


    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.martinstamenkovski:ARIndicatorView:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
}
```

Gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the BaseApplication

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication : Application()
```

What is the problem and how to solve it ?
I've been thinking about a solution for a long time and haven't found a solution!
I hope you can help me solve it.

Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

Try to update you Hilt dependencies to v2.40.2

```
// :app build.gradle START

plugins {
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
   //...
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
//...    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
//...
  
}

dependencies {

    //...
// hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40.2"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.40.2"

}

// Allow references to generated code
kapt {

    correctErrorTypes = true
}

 // :app build.gradle END
```

---

```
 // project build.gradle START

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        //...
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.2'

    }
}

// ...

// project build.gradle END
```

Comment: why this ? 
kapt {

    correctErrorTypes = true
}

Comment: Comes from the hilt + dagger setup doc. https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html